# Approximation of half-integers modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, approximation-algorithms, bessel-functions

I am trying to optimise the calculation of the probability distribution poisson-inverse-gaussian

its calculation involves a half-integers modified Bessel function of the second kind. Here's a formula for the probabilistic expression.

[image]

[Pubblication](https://www-jstor-org.ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au/stable/pdf/2288808.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Af3162035e441f86b360e2ed5919f6451)

For high input positive integer values, the calculation is very slow, as it involves a summation, or a recursion avoiding the Bessel in another formulation.

Is there an approximation for

$$
K_{x-1/2}(\alpha); x \gg 0
$$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/jmm.pdf

Comment: Do you want a large-$x$ expansion, or a large-$\alpha$ expansion? In any case, see [Spherical Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions:_jn,_yn) and their [asymptotics](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10).

Comment: Thanks. (I will use a probabilistic MCMC algorithm (Stan)) data counts $x$ can be high (e.g., 100.000) and the parameter $\alpha$ is "shape" I suppose is not >> 1

Comment: What do you mean by "high input positive integer values"?

Comment: @AmirSagiv for poisson_inverse_gaussian x = observed counts. So I am analysing gene expression where there could easily be and average of 100K copies for a given gene

Comment: Thanks @NoamD.Elkies, unfortunately I don't see anything about Bessel 2nd kind, and all  that math is a bit too involved for me at this stage.

Comment: Have you checked the asymptotic formulas at the DLMF site (https://dlmf.nist.gov)? In particular, https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41

Comment: @AndreiMF interesting! I assume you are talking about equation 10.41.2. This has an error of 0.000484% for v = 10.000. I assume a bit high, but it might work for extreme values of v. The goal is to get as close as possible to computational precision (about 16 digits).

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple saddle point approximation one can derive the following:
$$ [A] \quad K_y(a) \sim \frac{1}{2} \exp{(-r + y\,s)}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2r}}\Big( 1 + 
\text{erf}\big(\sqrt{\frac{r}{2}}\, s\big) \Big) \quad$$
where
$$ r=\sqrt{a^2+y^2} \text{ and } s=\text{arcsinh}(y/a) $$
I derived it from the known integral relation
$$ K_y(a) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-a\,\cosh(t))\cosh(y\,t) dt$$
Approximate $\cosh(yt) \sim 1/2 \exp{(yt)} .$  The integrand sans the 1/2 is $\exp(-a\,\cosh(t) + yt).$  Expand the argument of the exponential around its saddle point $s = \text{arcsinh}(y/a)$ and you get
$$   K_y(a) \sim \frac{1}{2} \exp{(-r + y\,s)} \int_0^\infty 
\exp{(-\frac{r}{2} (t-s)^2)}\, dt  $$
The integral evaluates to an error function, which is shown in [A].  Alternatively, if the argument of the error function is sufficiently large, say, >5, the the expression in the big parentheses can be approximated by 1.

Using Mathematica, for $y=x-1/2=10000,$ and $a=1/2$ I get about 6 significant figures agreement.  For $a=11/2,$ I get about 5 sig figs.  It is expected that this approximation will deteriorate as $a$ becomes comparable to $x$ but I haven't studied the limits.  Comments seem to indicate that $x>>a$ so this formula may be sufficient.  One can also get more terms by doing a complete expansion.

Comment: Thanks a lot @skbmoore. This error trend is also true if I truncate the summation in besselK to the interval [y-10, y]. I am currently trying to understand whether the shape parameter alpha can get of the same size as x (e.g., alpha = 100-1000, x = 1000).

Comment: I would up-vote your answer! But I am not allowed :(

Answer (score 1):

As I read Figure 2 in "Algorithm 644: A portable package for Bessel functions of a complex argument and nonnegative order" (D.E.Amos, https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=214331) you're veering dangerously close into 'overflow' territory.

Some experimentation with scipy.special.kv bears this out. Computing $K_{1000.5}(x)$ for $600\le x < 700$ gives values ranging from $K_{1000.5}(600) \approx 4.36527371e+49$ to $K_{1000.5}(700) \approx 3.73027792e-30$. (and plotting the logs produces a nearly-straight line, which suggests that this is in fact in the asymptotic region).

Looking at your original equation, I see an $x!$ in a denominator, and a $(\cdot)^x$  in a numerator, which aren't exactly going to make the numerics easier.    What I would recommend is switching to logspace and using the large-order approximation ( (10.41.2) on DLMF).  You'll have to tweak the MCMC update rules, but not in any particularly tricky way.

You might also be interested in this math.se question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1960778/approximating-the-log-of-the-modified-bessel-function-of-the-second-kind and some of the links therein.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to access this paper (paywall), but judging from the abstract it should provide what you are looking for: [Computation of the Poisson-inverse Gaussian distribution](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610928108828121)

> Recursion relations suitable for rapid computation are derived for the
>   probabilities of the compound Poisson distribution when the compounder
>   is the inverse-Gaussian distribution. Series representation of the
>   probabilities are given. Asymptotic results as well as approximations
>   for probabilities, compared with the exact values, are investigated.